# Recurly API : the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: .net, api, certificate, recurly

I have been trying to integrate the recurly API in our .Net application.

Public, Private Keys are being used as mentioned in the API Credentials Section. Domain name is also set to [mydomainname].

When it is trying to establish a connection. It throws an exception as follows

> "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure"

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at where you've configured your Recurly site subdomain and confirm if you've formatted as subdomain="mysubdomain" instead of mysubdomain.recurly.com. It's a common error that can cause a certificate validation error. The value "mysubdomain" is prepended to the base url within the library to form the call. More detail can be found at this link https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-net#configuration